# Can't get onEdit to call a function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to connect 2 spreadsheets, such that, I can perform a sumif function on one spreadsheet and get the result on the current one. I'm using onEdit installable trigger on function `when` since the simple trigger doesn't work. The dependant dropdown and also the sumif through a `for` loop works, but I can't seem to get the function `when` to call the function `sum` in order to set value on a cell. The sum function works separately and gives the result, but when executing onEdit it doesn't.
Also, is this the correct way to execute sumif? Is there any faster way(I require to execute it around 600-1000 times, here I kept it just 10 to test it out, which again is slow)?

My code follows:

'''

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var stck = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1WGbEo1Xr99HwHY_4ZaeTRIgCOuNcjVfqCzZx4dcQX4I");
var unisensor = stck.getSheetByName("Unisensor");

var ssOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Product List");
var options1 = ssOptions.getRange(2,1,ssOptions.getLastRow() - 1,2).getValues();


function When(e){

  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var ssName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  
  
 if (ssName=="Stock" && r==2 && c==1){
    ss.getRange(r,2).clearContent();
    ss.getRange(r,2).clearDataValidations();
    var filteredOptions = options1.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val});
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[1]});
    console.log(listToApply);
    var cell = ss.getRange(r,2);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
  }

 if (ssName=="Stock" && r==2 && c==2){
    var company = ss.getRange(r,1);
    if(company ==="Unisensor"){
      sum(val); 
    }
  }
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
 
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function sum(val){
  var res = 0;
  var result = ss.getRange(2,3);
    for (i =4;i<=10;i++){
      var cell = unisensor.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      var cellres = unisensor.getRange(i,9).getValue();
      if( cell == val){
        res+= cellres; 
      }
    }
  result.clearContent();
  result.setValue(res);
  Logger.log(res);
  }
```

'''

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If `when(e)` is being executed without errors, but `sum()` is not called, this means that your `if` condition is not fulfilled

Troubleshoot by implementing the following logs:

```js
function When(e){

  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var ssName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  
  
 if (ssName=="Stock" && r==2 && c==1){
    ss.getRange(r,2).clearContent();
    ss.getRange(r,2).clearDataValidations();
    var filteredOptions = options1.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val});
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[1]});
    console.log(listToApply);
    var cell = ss.getRange(r,2);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
  }

 if (ssName=="Stock" && r==2 && c==2){
    console.log('if (ssName=="Stock" && r==2 && c==2)')
    var company = ss.getRange(r,1);
    if(company ==="Unisensor"){
      console.log('company ==="Unisensor"')
      sum(val); 
    }
    else{
      console.log('NOT company ==="Unisensor"')
    }
  }
  else{
    console.log('NOT if (ssName=="Stock" && r==2 && c==2)')
  }
}
```

After the funciton executes on `onEdit` trigger - view the logs.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It seems the `if` condition is not fulfilled even though the value in that cell is the same as that in the condition. I don't know why is it this way, do you have an idea? Also is this the correct way to execute a sumif function?

Comment: Which of the two `if` conditions?

Comment: The second `if` condition:

Comment: Gives me the result: `NOT company ==="Unisensor"`

Comment: Then insert after the line `var company = ss.getRange(r,1);` the log `console.log(company)` and also try to modify `if(company ==="Unisensor")` to `if(company =="Unisensor")`

Comment: I've made the changes.  `console.log(company)` gives a blank output even though there is a value ("Unisensor").

Comment: It's okay. I figured I had to use `getValue()`. Thanks a lot @ziganotschka

Comment: Also, just wanted to know if this is the way to execute a sumif function, and is there a faster way? @ziganotschka

Comment: Why don't you just set the `sumif` [formula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)?

Comment: Actually, this `sumif` has to be executed on multiple sheets in a spreadsheet. I will be trying to build multiple `if` functions for separate sheets. Is this a good idea?